# What's the point of taking human prisoners in the Terminator series?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

...instead of killing them right away?

I mean, they tatoo people's wrists so that they can be scanned, and gather them in concentration camps, etc.

This happens in Genisys and in Terminator Salvation, at least.

It's acceptable that the terminators always waste a lot of time when attacking, but that is due to drama of course.

But the very point of *planning* a methodical way of gathering people, transporting them, etc. instead of killing them right away seems to me very unplausible.

Note: I know that concentration camps have some reasons to exist<sup>[citation needed]</sup> if we examine the history of human warfare, but in a machine-vs-human warfare I guess most of those reasons don't apply.

Comment: Well in T1, Reese says that humans were rounded up for orderly disposal. I think T Salvation was following that description that Reese gave. As to why exactly, they never say. I guess from a systematic computer point of view, it was just easier to round them up and exterminate them in mass. I believe they were also using their extra knowledge of future events to identify and wipe out people who it knew were part of the resistance, like the terminator from T3 was doing.